# plotting multiple graphs and animation from a data file in gnuplot

Tags: animation, plot, gnuplot, gif

Suppose I have the following sample data file.

```
0   1   2
0   3   4   
0   1   9
0   9   2
0   19  0
0   6   1
0   11  0
1   3   2
1   3   4   
1   1   6
1   9   2
1   15  0
1   6   6
1   11  1
2   3   2
2   4   4   
2   1   6
2   9   6
2   15  0
2   6   6
2   11  1
```

first column gives value of time. Second gives values of x and 3rd column y. I wish to plot graphs of y as functions of x from this data file at different times,

i.e, for t=0, I shall plot using 2:3 with lines up to t=0 index. Then same thing I shall do for the variables at t=1.

At the end of the day, I want to get a gif, i.e, an animation of how the y vs x graph changes shape as time goes on. How can I do this in gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? (Check `help ternary` and `help gif`)

You need to filter your data with the ternary operator  and then create the animation.

**Code:**

```
### plot filtered data and animate
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0   1   2
0   3   4   
0   1   9
0   9   2
0   19  0
0   6   1
0   11  0
1   3   2
1   3   4   
1   1   6
1   9   2
1   15  0
1   6   6
1   11  1
2   3   2
2   4   4   
2   1   6
2   9   6
2   15  0
2   6   
2   11  1
EOD

set terminal gif animate delay 50 optimize
set output "myAnimation.gif"

set xrange[0:20]
set yrange[0:10]
do for [i=0:2] {
    plot $Data u 2:($1==i?$3:NaN) w lp pt 7 ti sprintf("Time: %g",i)
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition**:

The meaning of `$1==i?$3:NaN` in words:

If the value in the first column is equal to `i` then the result is the value in the third column else it will be `NaN` ("Not a Number").

Comment: Can you please give a reference for these stuffs? Like the uses of syntax like "optimize","delay 50", ti, pt 7,"$1==i?$3:NaN" ......

Comment: In the gnuplot console type `help <keyword>`, e.g.
`optimize`, `delay` --> `help gif`;  `$1==i?$3:NaN` --> `help ternary`;
And `ti` is abbreviation for `title`, `pt` abbrev. for `pointtype`.
I cannot copy the full gnuplot manual here. Check this:
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/documentation.html